# What happens when a private IPv4 is assigned to multiple network interfaces?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, routes, ip

I am reading this [AWS networking doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html). It mentions that a secondary IPv4 can be reassigned to another network interface. I have the following questions regarding this behavior:

1. Will the traffic for the same IPv4 ever need to differentiate these network interfaces this same IPv4 assigned to?
2. Why doesn't IPv6 support this reassignment of network interface?
3. What defines an IPv4 to be primary or secondary?
4. Are those behavior mostly standard or something specific to AWS?

I am not sure if my questions even make sense. My understanding is that a traffic is targeting an IP not a network interface, but the traffic has to go through network interface first which sounds like just a grouping of IPs. Anyway, thank you in advance!

Comment: "_Why doesn't IPv6 support this reassignment of network interface?_" All IPv6 interfaces use the same link-local network, and you can assign the same link-local address on all the interfaces.

Comment: Is there a specific business issue you are trying to solve, or is this just out of general interest? The 'primary' IPv4 is the one attached to the first Elastic Network Interface and cannot be changed.

Comment: Thanks Ron! sorry that I still didn't understand how what you said is not conflicting with this sentence in that doc "An IPv6 address cannot be reassigned to another network interface; you must first unassign the IPv6 address from the existing network interface." Do you mean this is just peculiar in AWS?

Comment: Hi John, I don't have a specific use case, but thinking that's what generally will happen when you assign same IPv4 to multiple interfaces. I should have described more clearly, I read a situation somewhere that a "secondary" IPv4 is assigned to a primary interface, so I guess we only allow a single IPv4 to be primary in a primary interface? sorry it's kind boring since no real use case

Comment: _All_ IPv6 interfaces, even in the same host, use the same link-local network (`fe80::/64`), and you can set the same address in the link-local network on all of them, assuming they do not actually attach to the same layer-2 LAN. Duplicating any address (IPv4 or IPv6) on a layer-2 LAN will cause a duplicate address problem.

Comment: My understanding/guess is those interfaces referred in the doc are attached to the same layer-2 LAN then since that's same to the the way to solve the conflict between the two statements. Thank you!